# "Even though" vs. "even if"

Tags: phrases, differences

Are these two totally synonymous? Can one be used in place of the other anywhere? Are there any differences in nuance, or anything at all?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These two are not equivalent. *Even though* is used to introduce a condition which currently is true, while *even if* introduces a hypothetical condition that is not yet true.

> I'm going to the park *even though* it's raining.

This means that it's raining right now, but I'm going to the park anyway.

> I'm going to the park *even if* it's raining.

This means that it's not yet raining, but I will go to the park even if it starts to rain. Note that in this case the present progressive *I'm going* actually indicates a near future action.

Comment: +1 I believe that *even if* doesn't necessarily mean that the condition is *not true* (yet): it just means that the speaker doesn't consider it a fact; he might just not know whether it is true. An example: *we don't know how many bombers the Germans have; however, even if they have more than we do, they are easy prey for our superior fighters*. // (I believe many people might also use *even if* where you and I would only use *even though*; that is, they might use *even if* even when they know the condition is true.)

Comment: I would also add _even if_ can carry an indifference or reckless connotation. Very similar to the comment above but slightly different. _I will do it even though it will kill me._ sounds pretty resigned. _I will do it even if it will kill me._ meaning I'm sure it will kill me and I'm willing to do it anyway.

Comment: I think this answer is right. FYI: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv122.shtml