# How do I tell whether "even if" or "unless" is right?

Tags: conditionals, unless

Some say *unless* should fill the gap and others say *even if* should go there. How do I tell which one is correct?

> I couldn't have got to the airport on time yesterday .......... I had found a taxi.
>
> a. even if
> b. whether or not
> c. as long as
> d. unless
> e. providing that

Comment: The meaning of "even if" is different from "unless": you'll find "even if" in good dictionaries https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even-if

Comment: I'm still playing with (the acceptability of) 'I couldn't have got to the airport on time yesterday unless I had found a taxi.' I think I'd prefer 'I wouldn't have got ...' though I think this is a matter of idiomaticity, a grammatical grey area. Perhaps because the actuality is left unclear.  // But 'even if' works (with a different meaning, of course).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because both alternatives *(**unless, even if**)* are perfectly valid in the cited context, but *they mean completely different things*, as can easily be established using any online dictionary

Comment: Related: [“Even though” vs. “even if”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/even-though-vs-even-if)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't think it's the "acceptability" that's at issue here. It's just that the ***unless*** version is inherently ambiguous as regards whether I actually ***did*** get there or not (where the ***even if*** alternative implies I ***didn't***).

Comment: As I mentioned; Gricean maxims _forbid_ ambiguities. I'm not sure how this transfers to the use of 'unless' say in such structures. _Certainly not the best answer, but **wrong**?_

Comment: 'Unless' has caused enough doubts, another recent one being its interchangeability with 'except if'. I think the best interpretation to 'unless' is 'if not'. E.g., Unless you do it...If not you do it; rather If you do not do it..." It cannot stand for 'even if'.

Comment: Cross-posted at [forum.wordreference.com ... couldn't have - unless - whether or not -](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-couldn%E2%80%99t-have-unless-whether-or-not-%E2%80%A6.3789234/).

Comment: (c) and (e) are wrong. The rest are grammatical, though they don't mean the same things.

Answer (score 1):

Either ***even if*** or ***unless*** work be correct depending on the meaning of the sentence.

*I couldn't have got to the airport on time yesterday ***unless*** I had found a taxi.*

This suggests that you are telling it as if finding a taxi would be the only way to reach the airport and it doesn't imply whether or not you actually did find a taxi.

*I couldn't have got to the airport on time yesterday ***even if*** I had found a taxi.*

This one quite strongly suggests that you didn't find  a taxi. It also tells us that there was no way you could've reached the airport if you found a taxi or not.

These are the only two of the five options that make grammatical sense.

This answer is really just a mish-mash of the comments on this question, I found this to be the best explanation and thought it would be useful to have a proper answer to this.

Comment: I agree with your inclusion of only the two options *unless* and *even if* in your answer. The OP offers other options, none of which would make much sense idiomatically.

Comment: Yes, I may add that to the answer